# Getting IDs where created before a specific date and not referenced after that date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get a list of IDs back from a query that depends on the value in an ID reference column and date column in another row.

Basically, I'm trying to retrieve the `ID` for records that have been created before a specified date (`Created` column) *unless* this record is referenced by another (by the `RefID` column) created after this date.

(I plan to use this in a sproc at some point, but just using a variable for the time being)

Very simple example table below. Left out unrelated columns for simplicity.

```
+--------+---------+---------------+
|   ID   |  RefID  |    Created    |
+--------+---------+---------------+
|  123   |  NULL   |  2016-10-18   |
|  456   |  123    |  2016-10-20   |
|  789   |  NULL   |  2016-10-18   |
|  111   |  789    |  2016-10-18   |
+--------+---------+---------------+
```

So in my example table above, if I specified 2016-10-19 I would get IDs 789 and 111 back. I would not get 123 because although it was created before 2016-10-18, it is referenced by 456 which was not (therefore I would also not get 456 back).

I've been fiddling with variations on joining, but SQL is definitely not my strong area, so I feel like I'm running in circles, and chasing the wrong solution at that!
I have this so far, which I *think* is getting me the correct list of IDs referenced after a certain date. I'm not quite sure how to exclude this list from my main query...let alone what an appropriate main query would be.

```
DECLARE @myDate datetime
SET @myDate = '2016-10-19'

SELECT t1.id
FROM MyDB.dbo.[myTable] AS t1
JOIN MyDB.dbo.[myTable] AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.ref_id
WHERE t1.id = t2.ref_id AND t2.created > @myDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it with `not exists` with a condition to check if the referenced id has a row after the specified date.

```
SELECT id
FROM MyDB.dbo.[myTable] t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyDB.dbo.[myTable] 
                  WHERE t1.id = ref_id 
                  AND created > @myDate) 
AND created < @myDate
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/DDFACN68190)

Comment: Would I be able to expand this to consider 2 different dates? Say if I wanted IDs from before date [X], and if they were referenced, the reference must be created before date [Y]?

Comment: sure..you can do that.

Comment: Sorry, just making sure before I start blindly throwing values in to test. Would that just be a using variable [X] for the `@myDate` on line 6 and a new variable [Y] on the `@myDate` on line 5?

Comment: yes the inner condition checks to see if any of the ref_id's have a later date and the outer condition is the id's before a given date. you can modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> **EDITED**: I realized (after the accepted solution and re-reading the original request) you were not asking to exclude t1 records that had related t2 records after t1 creation, but after the "mydate" date. I changed my queries below accordingly (I guess, however, that vkp query is also better performing than my revised answer).

I started from your query and arrived to this proposal:

```
 SELECT t1.id
   FROM MyDB.dbo.[myTable] AS t1
   LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.[myTable] AS t2
     ON t1.id = t2.ref_id and t2.created > @mydate
  WHERE t2.id is null AND t1.created < @mydate
```

So, for the table t1 (before a specified date), I'm joining (if they exist) all the cases with a created date greater than the "mydate" one, and ref_id equal to t1.id.
After that, I say that I don't want the rows where I found a match (that's the use of `t2.id is null`) thus leaving me with the desired resultset.

As for the last addition to the request (having a different "starting date" for reference in records to exclude),  you would just need to modify the query as this:

```
 SELECT t1.id
   FROM MyDB.dbo.[myTable] AS t1
   LEFT JOIN MyDB.dbo.[myTable] AS t2
     ON t1.id = t2.ref_id 
     and t2.created > @exclusionstartdate
  WHERE t2.id is null AND t1.created < @mydate
```